# Is there a way to get DisableUserModeCallbackFilter to work in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, kernel-mode, stack-unwinding

Is there any way to get [`DisableUserModeCallbackFilter`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976038/exceptions-that-are-thrown-from-an-application-that-runs-in-a-64-bit-v) (or similar) to work on Windows 10?

It's supposed to allow exceptions thrown from user-mode code to propagate across user/kernel boundaries, and it had a hotfix on earlier Windows versions up to Windows 7, but I can't seem seem to be able to get it working on more recent versions.

Here's a test program that seems to error on Windows 10 x64, but not on Windows XP x86:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

WNDPROC oldproc = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK newproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    _ftprintf(stderr, _T("OMG\n"));
    fflush(stderr);
    throw 0;
    return oldproc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Name"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    oldproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)newproc);
    try {
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    } catch (int ex) {
        _ftprintf(stderr, _T("Error: %d\n"), ex);
        fflush(stderr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Entering dangerous territory, tread carefully. [When you transfer control across stack frames, all the frames in between need to be in on the joke](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120910-00/?p=6653).

Comment: *across user/kernel boundaries* - you are about ? exception passed to user mode as usual (if not handled by debugger before). problem in `KiUserCallbackDispatcherHandler` (this is user mode routine from *ntdll.dll*). it behavior depend from `RtlGetCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->Flags`  - 0x80000 flag. the `SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy` set or reset this flag now it not exported but you can set this flag yourself (`RtlGetCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->Flags |= 0x80000;`) after this will be no fatal error, but your handler anyway will be not called

Comment: It is a hack to make Win7/Server2008 behave better, default behavior is rather dreadful.  They found a much better solution in Win8, re-raising 0xC000041D is pretty effective.  Just don't try to defeat a good solution.  Targeting x64 is a good solution as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: confused, targeting x64 doesn't make any difference here though? Either way the exception handler at the top isn't called.

Answer (score 2):

when window procedure called - kernel push additional stack frame in kernel stack and in user mode called special "function" (faster even label then normal function) `KiUserCallbackDispatcher`, which call window procedure and finally return to kernel by special api call `ZwCallbackReturn` pop kernel stack frame. note that after call `ZwCallbackReturn` we return not to next instruction after it, but in place from where we enter to kernel, from where user mode callback will be called (usually from `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`).

anyway we must pop kernel stack frame - so call `ZwCallbackReturn`. so case with unwind exception across `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` - is wrong by design and must not work. who in this case call `ZwCallbackReturn` ? if it will be called from `__finally` handler in `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` - this break unwind procedure ( `ZwCallbackReturn` how i say never return, but like long jump - move us to another place with another stack pointer and all registers). even if you manually call `ZwCallbackReturn` from `catch` - where you will be after this call ?

so need handle exception before `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` *SEH* handler or how minimum have `__finally` blocks, if need de-allocate some resources.

`KiUserCallbackDispatcher` used `SEH` handler for call `ZwCallbackReturn` even if exception will be in callback. however behavior of this *SEH* handler can be affected by undocumented flag in  `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.Flags` :

pseudo-code:

```
void KiUserCallbackDispatcher(...)
{
    __try {

        //...
    } __except(KiUserCallbackExceptionFilter(GetExceptionInformation())) {
KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue:
        ZwCallbackReturn(0, 0, 0);
    }
}

void LdrpLogFatalUserCallbackException(PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord, PCONTEXT ContextRecord);

int KiUserCallbackExceptionFilter(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS pep)
{
    if ( NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->Flags & 0x80000)
    {
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }

    LdrpLogFatalUserCallbackException(pep->ExceptionRecord, pep->ContextRecord);

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}
```

if this flag (`0x80000`) not set (by default) - `LdrpLogFatalUserCallbackException` called. it internally call `UnhandledExceptionFilter` and if it not return `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` - called [`ZwRaiseException`](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a0f349c0a0fcbdf678fca532556db2d8c) with `STATUS_FATAL_USER_CALLBACK_EXCEPTION` and `FirstChance = FALSE` (this mean this exception not passed to application - only for debugger as last chance exception)

if we set this flag - `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER` will be returned from filter - [`RtlUnwindEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680615(v=vs.85).aspx) will be called (with `TargetIp = KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue`) - as result `__finally` handlers will be called and at the end `ZwCallbackReturn(0, 0, 0);`

in any case exception will be not passed to SEH in function which is **higher** in stack, than `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` (because here exception will be handled)

so we need handle exception in stack below `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` or set flags to `0x80000` - in this case, if we not handle exception before `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` - our `__finally` blocks (if exist) will be executed before `ZwCallbackReturn` which finish callback.

[`SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976038/exceptions-that-are-thrown-from-an-application-that-runs-in-a-64-bit-v) not exported in recent windows versions (begin from win8), but yearly code of this api was next(exactly code):

```
#define PROCESS_CALLBACK_FILTER_ENABLED     0x1

BOOL WINAPI SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy(DWORD dwFlags)
{
    PLONG pFlags = (PLONG)&NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->Flags;
    if (dwFlags & PROCESS_CALLBACK_FILTER_ENABLED)
    {
        _bittestandset(pFlags, 19); // |= 0x80000
    }
    else
    {
        _bittestandreset(pFlags, 19); // &= ~0x80000
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

test:

```
WNDPROC oldproc;

LRESULT CALLBACK newproc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)oldproc);
    __try {
        *(int*)0=0;
        //RaiseException(STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, 0, 0, 0);

    } __finally {
        DbgPrint("in finally\n");
        CallWindowProc(oldproc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void test()
{
    RtlGetCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->Flags |= 0x80000;

    if (HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, WC_EDIT, L"***", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        oldproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)newproc);
        __try {
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        }__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER){
            DbgPrint("no sense. never will be called\n");
        }

        MSG msg;
        while (0 < GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0))
        {
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

try comment or un-comment `RtlGetCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->Flags |= 0x80000;` line (or `NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters->Flags & 0x80000` which is the same) and compare effect.

anyway top SEH filter (before call wndproc) never will be called

Comment: As always, none of this is guaranteed to work, or even documented. This needs to be explicitly noted in this answer, that currently reads, as if this were a supported scenario. There is a reason, why Microsoft have been making it increasingly harder, to pass exceptions across foreign stack frames. C++ code should probably use C++11 facilities (like [std::rethrow_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/rethrow_exception)), where possible, to transfer exception objects across foreign stack frames.

Comment: @IInspectable - what question is that and the answer. question at begin touch almost undocumented topics. if want be in documentation limits - no answer at all. or answer - impossible. really catch exception in `_tmain` anyway impossible. but partially possible change behavior of exception handler. all what i try do here - some explain how it internal worked. and this not related to c++ exception (which is shell over windows exception). main - exception in callback of course passed to user mode as usual, but handled in `KiUserCallbackDispatcher` *SEH*

Comment: There is no such thing as *"almost undocumented"*, in the same way as there is no such thing as *"almost pregnant"*. The OP has linked to an official KB entry, and uses what *is* documented there. Your answer presents a solution, that is based off of solely undocumented implementation details. I proposed an alternative when using C++ exceptions (like the OP), because it already provides facilities to pass exception objects by value. If you want to implement a similar scheme for SEH exceptions, I'm sure that is possible, too. But the OP is using C++ exceptions.

Comment: @IInspectable - i only try explain how it internal works. and i can not understand - how do you know that this is not documented - i did not write explicitly about it. strange

Comment: anyway - code of "documented" `SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy` is exactly - taken from win7. if somebody want - can get this code and test, how exception route in callback will change after set flag. or direct call `RtlGetCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->Flags |= 0x80000;`. maximum what we can achieve with this - avoid fatal error and, if need, execute `__finally`  handlers, for free some resources

Comment: `SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy` is not available in any of the systems, the OP is asking about. It also appears, that you did not understand, what the OP is trying to do: They want to handle C++ exceptions raised in callbacks at the call site. At any rate, giving feedback on your submissions is discarded as a general rule. Any opinion is wrong, unless it is yours. I'll just stop wasting my time here.

Comment: @IInspectable - *SetProcessUserModeExceptionPolicy is not available in any of the systems* - i wrote about this in answer. but i paste it actual code from win7 - very simply implement it yourself. or `RtlGetCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameters->Flags |= 0x80000` - the same. if you can read. and op not ask about only `c++` exception. question was about exception in general. my answer is informational.